# React Building a CMS with dashboard how to show hide Dashboard component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i built a react app (simple CMS) with couple components, most components are available for visitors, in the main(App.js) component.
 i use react router to  display components,
 i made Dashboard component available only for admins, thru example.com/dashboard. 
 i built a login system using node.js and JWT i did all the logic.
 but i dont know the proper way to show hide the dashboard component.
 i tried to use 
but i cant understand the logic, please show me what the best strategy to show hide the dashboard in the react app.
is it safe to use if else logic showing/hiding Dashboard. or its not secure to use that? 
My question: is there a react way to do the job

exapmle:

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
     |components/
      |Clien/
        |Home.js
        |Home.css
        |Header.js
        |Footer.js
        |Login.js
      |admin/
        |Dashboard.js
        |Dashboard.css
      App.css
      App.js
      index.css
      index.js
      logo.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of whether or not your user is logged in through some global state, or `localStorage`. Then you can do something like this:

```
<Route render={(props) => (
    state.isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
)} />
```

Keep in mind that a malicious use could just go open up devtools and change `isAuthenticated` to `true`, so whatever content you are serving in the dashboard also needs to be protected by authentication.

Comment: thanks for the answer thats what im afraid of malicious use can you provide a link for a proper way to create private routing, thank you

Comment: there really isn't any way to perfectly protect a client-side route since the user has access to your component code. The best you can do is make sure the data you are showing on your dashboard is served from your api/server only if the user's JWT is valid (which it looks like you already have that in place)

Comment: thank you that make sense, so their is no way we can hid the dashboard from malicious use, my only choice is to depend on JWT